# Remove all but every 12th file

Tags: bash, rm

I have a few thousand files in the format filename.12345.end . I only want to keep every 12th file, so file.00012.end, file.00024.end ... file.99996.end and delete everything else.

The files may also have numbers earlier in their filename, and are normally of the form: `file.00064.name.99999.end`

I use Bash shell and can't figure out how to loop over the files and then get out the number and check whether it is `number%%12=0`  deleting the file if not. Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
Dorina

Comment: Is the number of the file just dependent on the filename?

Comment: Also, do the files always have 5 digits, and are the suffix and the prefix always the same?

Comment: Yes it is always 5 digits. I am not sure if I get your first question right. Files with different filenames are different, and I need these specific files which happen to have the numbers 00012, 00024 etc.

Comment: OK I meant are the filenames different, and are the extensions, like `.end` different? It should be OK though.

Comment: ah, ok. well, there actually is another number in the filename, it is actually like file.00064.name.99999.end the second number is the one of which I only need every 12th and of the first number is 0-63, so I actually have 64 different filenames + the number. the ending is always the same. But just knowing how to do it for one filename would help me a lot.

Comment: @Dorina please [edit] your question and make that clear. It changes everything!

Comment: And they're all in the same directory, right ?

Answer (score 18):

Here's a Perl solution. This should be much faster for thousands of files:

```
perl -e '@bad=grep{/(\d+)\.end/ && $1 % 12 != 0}@ARGV; unlink @bad' *
```

Which can be further condensed into:

```
perl -e 'unlink grep{/(\d+)\.end/ && $1 % 12 != 0}@ARGV;' *
```

If you have too many files and can't use the simple `*`, you can do something like:

```
perl -e 'opendir($d,"."); unlink grep{/(\d+)\.end/ && $1 % 12 != 0} readdir($dir)'
```

As for speed, here's a comparison of this approach and the shell one provided in one of the other answers:

```
$ touch file.{01..64}.name.{00001..01000}.end
$ ls | wc
  64000   64000 1472000
$ time for f in ./* ; do file="${f%.*}"; if [[ $((10#${file##*.} % 12)) -ne 0 ]]; then rm "$f"; fi; done

real    2m44.258s
user    0m9.183s
sys     1m7.647s

$ touch file.{01..64}.name.{00001..01000}.end
$ time perl -e 'unlink grep{/(\d+)\.end/ && $1 % 12 != 0}@ARGV;' *

real    0m0.610s
user    0m0.317s
sys     0m0.290s
```

As you can see, the difference is enormous, [as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303157/22222).

#### Explanation

- The `-e` is simply telling `perl` to run the script given on the command line.
- `@ARGV` is a special variable containing all the arguments given to the script. Since we're giving it `*`, it will contain all the files (and directories) in the current directory.
- The `grep` will search through the list of file names and look for any that match a string of numbers, a dot and `end` (`/(\d+)\.end/)`.
- Because the numbers (`\d`) are in a capture group (parentheses), they are saved as `$1`. So the `grep` will then check whether that number is a multiple of 12 and, if it isn't, the file name will be returned. In other words, the array `@bad` holds the list of files to be deleted.
- The list is then passed to `unlink()` which removes files(but not directories).

Answer (score 12):

Given that your filenames are in the format `file.00064.name.99999.end`, we first need to trim away everything except our number. We'll use a `for` loop to do this.

We also need to tell the Bash shell to use base 10, because Bash arithmetic will treat them numbers beginning with a 0 as base 8, which will mess things up for us.

As a script, to be launched when in the directory containing files use:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./*
do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
    file="${f%.*}"
    if [[ $((10#${file##*.} % 12)) -ne 0 ]]; then
      rm "$f"
    fi
  else
    echo "$f is not a file, skipping."
  fi
done
```

Or you can use this very long ugly command to do the same thing:

```
for f in ./* ; do if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then file="${f%.*}"; if [[ $((10#${file##*.} % 12)) -ne 0 ]]; then rm "$f"; fi; else echo "$f is not a file, skipping."; fi; done
```

To explain all of the parts:

- `for f in ./*` means for everything in the current directory, do.... This sets each file or directory found as the variable $f.
- `if [[ -f "$f" ]]` checks whether the item found is a file, if not we skip to the `echo "$f is not...` part, which means we don't start deleting directories accidentally.
- `file="${f%.*}"` sets the $file variable as the filename trimming off whatever comes after the last `.`.
- `if [[ $((10#${file##*.} % 12)) -eq 0 ]]` is where the main Arithmetic kicks in. The `${file##*.}` trims everything before the last `.` in our filename without extension. `$(( $num % $num2 ))` is the syntax for Bash arithmetic to use the modulo operation, the `10#` at the start tells Bash to use base 10, to deal with those pesky leading 0s. `$((10#${file##*.} % 12))` then leaves us the remainder of our filenames number divided by 12. `-ne 0` checks whether the remainder is "not equal" to zero.
- If the remainder is not equal to 0, the file is deleted with the `rm` command, you may want to replace `rm` with `echo` when first running this, to check that you get the expected files to delete.

This solution is non-recursive, meaning that it will only process files in the current directory, it won't go into any sub-directories.

The `if` statement with the `echo` command to warn about directories is not really necessary as `rm` on it's own will complain about directories, and not delete them, so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./*
do
  file="${f%.*}"
  if [[ $((10#${file##*.} % 12)) -ne 0 ]]; then
    rm "$f"
  fi
done
```

Or

```
for f in ./* ; do file="${f%.*}"; if [[ $((10#${file##*.} % 12)) -ne 0 ]]; then rm "$f"; fi; done
```

Will work correctly too.

Comment: Calling `rm` a few thousand times can be quite slow. I suggest to `echo` the file name instead and pipe the output of the loop to `xargs rm` (add options as needed): `for f in *; do if ... ; then echo "$f"; fi; done | xargs -rd '\n' -- rm --`.

Comment: I've edited to include your suggested speed improvement.

Comment: Actually after testing on a directory with 55999 files, the original version took 2mins 48secs, the `xargs` version took 5mins 1 sec. Could this be due to overhead on `echo` @DavidFoerster ?

Comment: Odd. For 60.000 files I get 0m0.659s/0m0.545s/0m0.380s (real/user/sys) with `time { for f in *; do echo "$f"; done | xargs rm; }` vs. 1m11.450s/0m10.695s/0m16.800s with `time { for f in *; do rm "$f"; done; }` on a tmpfs. Bash is v4.3.11, Kernel is v4.4.19.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Bash bracket expansion to generate names containing every 12th number. Let's create some test data

```
$ touch file.{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}.end # create test data
$ mv file.00024.end file.00024.end.name.99999.end # testing this form of filenames
```

Then we can use the following

```
$ ls 'file.'{00012..100..12}* # print these with numbers less than 100
file.00012.end                 file.00036.end  file.00060.end  file.00084.end
file.00024.end.name.99999.end  file.00048.end  file.00072.end  file.00096.end
$ rm 'file.'{00012..100000..12}* # do the job
```

Works hopelessly slow for large amount of files though - it takes time and memory to generate thousands of names - so it's more a trick that actual efficient solution.

Comment: I like the code-golfing on this one.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit long, but is what came to my mind.

```
 for num in $(seq 1 1 11) ; do
     for sequence in $(seq -f %05g $num 12 99999) ; do
         rm file.$sequence.end.99999;
     done
 done
```

Explanation:
Delete every 12th file eleven times.

Answer (score 0):

In all humbleness I think this solution is a lot nicer than the other answer:

```
find . -name '*.end' -depth 1 | awk 'NR%12 != 0 {print}' | xargs -n100 rm
```

A little explanation: First we generate a list of files with `find`. We get all files whose name ends with `.end` and which are at a depth of 1 (that is to say, they're directly in the working directory and not in any subfolders. You can leave that out if there are no subfolders). The output list will be sorted alphabetically.

Then we pipe that list into `awk`, where we use the special variable `NR` which is the line number. We leave out every 12th file by printing the files where `NR%12 != 0`. The `awk` command can be shortened to `awk 'NR%12'`, because the result of the modulo operator gets interpreted as a boolean value and the `{print}` is implicitly done anyway.

So now we have a list of files that need to be deleted, which we can do with xargs and rm. `xargs` runs the given command (`rm`) with the standard input as arguments.

If you have many files, you'll get an error saying something like 'argument list too long' (on my machine that limit is 256 kB, and the minimum required by POSIX is 4096 bytes). This can be avoided by the `-n 100` flag, which splits the arguments up every 100 words (not lines, something to watch out for if your file names have spaces) and executes a separate `rm` command, each with only 100 arguments.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your approach:  `-depth` needs to be before `-name`; ii) this will fail if any of the file names contain whitespace; iii) you are assuming the files will be listed in ascending numerical order (that's what your `awk` is testing for) but this will almost certainly not be the case. Therefore, this will delete a random set of files.

Comment: d'oh! You're quite right, my bad (comment edited). I got the error because of the wrong placement and didn't remember `-depth`. Still, that was the least of the issues here, the most important one is that you're deleting a random set of files and not the ones the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, and no, `-depth` doesn't take a value  and it does the opposite of what you think it does. See `man find`: "-depth Process each directory's contents before the  directory  itself.". So this will actually descend into subdirectories and wreak havoc all over the place.

Comment: I) Both `-depth n` and `-maxdepth n` exist. The former requires the depth to be exactly n, and with the latter it can be <= n. II). Yes, that's bad but for this particular example it's no concern. You could fix it by using `find ... -print0 | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\0"}; NR%12 != 0' | xargs -0 -n100 rm`, which uses the null byte as record separator (which isn't allowed in filenames).  III) Once again, in this case the assumption is reasonable. Otherwise you could insert a `sort -n` between `find` and `awk`, or redirect `find` to a file and sort it however you like.

Comment: Well, no, that's not what `-depth` does, see my previous comment. And yes, I did just look it up. Yes, that's exactly how to fix the whitespace issue (why not include that in your answer?). Your last point is still wrong though and `sort -n` won't fix it. See the OP's comment [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/824004/rm-all-but-every-12th-file/824075#comment1251864_824004). Her files are like `file.00064.name.99999.end` so they won't be sorted numerically by default at all. In any case, `find` never sorts, even if the files were perfectly sortable. Try `touch {a..z}; find`.

Comment: Well we seem to have different `find` version, my man page says the following: 

     -depth  Always true; same as the -d option.

     -depth n
             True if the depth of the file relative to the starting point of the traversal is n.

Comment: Ah, you're probably using OSX then. That's a very different implementation of `find`. Again, however, the main issue is that you're assuming that `find` returns a sorted list. It doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, find usually finds files in directory entry order, which ls sorts before displaying.  Directory entry order is usually the order that the files were created in the directory (and if files are delete and other files are added, those files will go in those slots).  Basically, you can't count on find returning files in sorted order.  You have to sort yourself before processing.

Answer (score 0):

For using only bash, my first approach would be to: 1. move all files you want to keep into another directory (ie. all those whose number in filename is a multiple of 12) then 2. delete all remaining files in the directory, then 3. put the multiple-of-12 files you kept back where they were. So something like this might work:

```
cd dir_containing_files
mkdir keep_these_files
n=0
while [ "${n}" -lt 99999 ]; do
  padded_n="`echo -n "00000${n}" | tail -c 5`"
  mv "filename${padded_n}.end" keep_these_files/
  n=$[n+12]
done
rm filename*.end
mv keep_these_files/* .
rmdir keep_these_files
```

Comment: I like the approach, but how do you generate the `filename` part if it's not consistent?